# jQuery().fadeIn() to an ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I have following jQuery to allow hidden content to be shown:

```
jQuery(".button").click(function(){  
    jQuery("#hidden_content").fadeIn()   
    return false;
});
```

Here is a simple image of what happens when the button is clicked:

[image]

Problem is that when the hidden content is visible, the page is scrolled down slightly that the `visible content 1` is "obstructed" (if that is the right word).

Let say that the `visible content 1` has an `id` of "#my_visible_content_1".
When the button is clicked, is there a way to use this `id` to position what is at the top?

Or even disabling scrolling would work.

Comment: Well, it is not a css problem though (at least I don't think). There is no overflowing content. The hidden content pushes pretty much all other contents and the page orientates itself to the start of the hidden content. I am trying to keep the page not scrolled, if that makes sense.

Comment: Can you share the full HTML + CSS + JS code?

Comment: Why does the page get scrolled?

Comment: Well, you did write *"Or even disabling scrolling would work."*, and that's exactly what `overflow : hidden` does ?

Comment: can you post html also,otherwise a fiddle?

Comment: Normally it won't happen. I think your issue is specific to the page/css you are working. Is the container DIv is position: absolute/fixed ? It would be more clear if you can put your actual code here.

Comment: I see. Yeah I figured out that it was css problem. I got it working. Thanks guys for the help. :-)